# Is there any way that I make the PHP at server side to perform some kind of actions on the data on it's own?

Tags: php, cron, fork

I have this scenario:

User submits a link to my PHP website and closes the browser. Now that the server has got the link it will analyse the submitted link (page) for the broken links and after it has completely analysed the posted link, it will send an email to the user. I have a complete understanding of the second part i.e. how to analyse the page for the broken links and send the mail to the user. Only problem that I have is how may I achieve this first part i.e. make the server keep running the actions on it's own even even if there is no request made by the client end?

I have learned that "Crontab" or a "fork" may work for me. What do you say about these? Is it possible to achieve what I want, using these? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

crontab would be the way to go for something like this.

Essentially you have two applications:

- A web site where users submit data to a database.
- An offline script, scheduled to run via `cron`, which checks for records in the database and performs the analysis, sending notifications of the results when complete.

Both of these applications share the same database, but are otherwise oblivious to each other.

A website itself isn't suited well for this sort of offline work, it's mainly a request/response system.  But a scheduled task works for this.  Unless the user is expecting an immediate response, a small delay of waiting for the next scheduled run of the offline task is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The server should run the script independently of the browser.  Once the request is submitted, the php server runs the script and returns the result to the browser (if it has a result to return)

An alternative would be to add the request to a database and then use crontab run the php script at a given interval.  The script would then check the database to see if there's anything that needs to be processed.  You could limit the script to run one database entry every minute (or whatever works). This will help prevent performance problems if you have a lot of requests at once, but will be slower to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach would be to enter the link into a database when the user submits it. You would then use a cron job to execute a script periodically, which will process any pending links.

Exactly how to setup a cron job (or equivalent scheduled task) depends on your server. If you have a host which provides a web-based admin tool (such as CPanel), there will often be a way to do it in there.

Answer (score 0):

PHP script will keep running after the client closes the broser (terminating the connection).

Only keep in mind PHP scripts maximum execution time is limited to "max_execution_time" directive value.

Of course here I suppose the link submission happens calling your script page... I don't understand if this is your use case...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, a cronjob could do the wonders. User submits a link, the web handler simply saves the link into a DB (let me pretend here that the table is named "queued_links"). Then a cronjob scheduled to run each minute (for example), selects every `link` from `queued_links`, does the application logic (finds broken page links) and sends the email. It then also deletes the link from `queued_links` (or updates a flag to represent the fact that the `link` has already been processed.

In the sake of scale and speed, a cronjob wouldn't fit as well as a Message Queue (see rabbitmq, activemq, gearman, and beanstalkd (gearman and beanstalk are my favorite 2, simple and fit well with php)). In lieu of spawning a cronjob every minute, a queue processor listens for 'events' and asynchronously processes the 'events' (think 'onLinkSubmission($link)'), and processes the messages ASAP. The cronjob solution is just a simplified implementation of one of these MQ solutions, will result in better / more predictable results, but at the cost of adding new services to maintain, etc.

Answer (score 0):

well, there are couple of ways, simplest of them would be:
When user submit a request, save this request some where, let's call it jobs table, and inform customer that his request has been received, they'll be updated site finish processing your request, or whatever suites you.

Now, create a (or multiple) scripts (depending upon requirement) and run this script from Cron, this script will pick requests from Job table, process it, do whatever required.

Alternatively, you can evaluate possibility of message_queue or may be using a Job server for this.

so, it all depends on your requirement.